# Редирект при выборе checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть два чекбокса

```
<input type="checkbox" value="asc" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="desc">
```

Один чекбокс всегда `checked`.

Помогите решить две задачи:

1) Всегда выбран один чекбокс. Два выбранных или два пустых не бывает. При нажатии на выбранный чекбокс - ничего не происходит. При нажатии на пустой - он становится `checked`, а первый пустой( как на radio button)

2) Как при смене выбранного checkbox'а, делать редирект на другую страницу.

Например если выбрали второй чекбокс, то должен произойти редирект на страницу "?sort=desc"

Comment: 1) таких вопросов уже задано достаточно 2) что вы сделали доя решения проблемы и с чем столкнулись?

Comment: Почему бы не заменить чекбоксы на radio с изначально выбранным одним вариантом? Это решает п.п. 1 средствами браузера.

Answer (score 2):

1. При выборе одного из чекбоксов снимайте выделение у второго. При снятии выделения у одного из чекбоксов - устанавливайте выбор на другой.
2. Обрабатывайте событие выбора чекбокса и проверяйте его value, при совпадении с необходимым значением производите редирект

Answer (score 0):

Для примера код:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
  var th = $(this);
  if(th.prop('checked')){
    return false;
  }
  // переадресация
  window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?sort=' + th.val();
});
```

Данный код не учитывает наличие других url параметров, но текущую задачу выполняет